# Exception when execute jar file from cmd

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, jar

I want to execute an spring based jar file from cmd.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>granzplast</groupId>
<artifactId>fileserver</artifactId>

<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.json</artifactId>
        <version>chargebee-1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<!-- Build an executable JAR -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>granzplast.fileserver.Application</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
   </plugins>
```

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

I created a jar file in intelliJ and it went ok, but when I do: java -jar fileserver-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

I get:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication

EDIT: [Cmd error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5bmv.png)

Mvn clean package:
[mvn clean package from intelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRKbq.png)

```
    [INFO] Building fileserver 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ fileserver ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\anna_\IdeaProjects\fileserver\target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.624 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-03-25T13:53:51+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've been looking for other answers but no one worked for me. Hope someone can help

Comment: pom.xml has Unexpected tokens

Comment: @Anna Actually `spring-boot-maven-plugin` adds the dependencies to the jar file. are you share `repackage` goal is executed?

Comment: @hatefalipoor don't understand, what do u mean with repackage?

Comment: do you see this line in cmd `[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:repackage (repackage) @ fileserver ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive`

Comment: no, I don't see it, I updated the question with an screenshot of what cmd says

Comment: @Anna I mean when you execute `mvn clean package`

Comment: @hatefalipoor no, I don't see it, I updated the question and copied what i get with mvn clean

Comment: @Anna please run `mvn clean package` not just `mvn clean`

Comment: @hatefalipoor updated: added an image how I did it from intelliJ "mvn clean package from intelliJ"

Answer (score 0):

Either you code has some static references that is not getting resolved or the fat jar has some dependency library missing
[Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java/66816030#66816030)